# The font used for the Microsoft Help Viewer (2.1) content tree is too small. Can it be changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, help-viewer

Please see the [image: screenshot].

Also, I am not too sure if it is related, but I use resharper and the font used in the Usages of '...' window (that shows the usages of a class, for instance) is as small as the one in the Help Viewer. I would like to change that as well. I wouldn't be surprised if there is a setting somewhere that controls both.

Thank you.